# Light switch tripping

Tags: wiring, light

hoping to get your feedback on what could be going wrong here. Hope you can understand my diagram. When switch 2 is flipper on it trips the breaker. In the light 2 jbox there is no light installed yet but I connected the wires together in anticipation and this is when I found the issue. There are also grounds and they are all connected to the light plate and not touching any other wires. Any ideas what could be going haywire?

Derrick

[image]

Comment: Why, oh why, are you switching the neutral?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem.  The cable between light 2 and S2 is what's called a *switch loop*.  Switch loops don't have neutral.  They have **always-hot** and **switched-hot**. These are the two wires you connect to a switch.

If you want to wire by colors, switched hot is usually red.  You're seeing white because the store doesn't sell Romex in black-red.  The installer was forced to use stock black-white.  There's an exception to the rule allowing white wires to be used for hots in this case (however, it also says you must remark the wires by wrapping them with electrical tape or other method). So get some red electrical tape and mark both ends of the white wire as red.

You never attach neutral to a plain switch, this would result in a short when the switch is turned on.

**The white wire in a switch loop is not neutral.**

Switches get always-hot and switched-hot... and not neutral.

Lamps get switched-hot and neutral. They can't use always-hot because then you wouldn't be able to switch it.    You would never splice switched-hot and neutral together, as it would be a short when the switch is turned on.

This drawing shows the problem.  Joining switched-hot to neutral up in the light box is causing the short when the light is turned on.

[image]

How do you tell if a white wire is in-use as a switched-hot? By following the wires and seeing if it

- has black/colored tape (now required)
- is one of only 2 conductors in a switch loop (therefore it must)
- is landed on a non-smartswitch
- is  spliced into a group of hots
- goes directly to a lamp but there's another wire known to be neutral
- lights up a voltage detector when the switch is on.  This can be a problem if the switch is broken.   *To make this last one easier, best practice is to use the white as the always-hot, and the black for the switched-hot.*

Comment: Are you saying the hot/n wires are reversed??

Comment: @DerrickK I'm saying the white wire between Light 2 and S2 **is not neutral**.  It should in fact be red, since it is switched-hot.  Hence, nutting red and white together at Light 2 is not a thing you should do. Those two wires should go to a lamp instead of a nut.  If you don't have a lamp, cap them off separately.

Comment: How can you tell if a neutral is switche hot?

Comment: @DerrickK See edits, and stop saying "neutral" when you mean "white" :)

Comment: @derrickk get a professional before you burn your house down! Harper explained how switch loops work and you have obviously mis wired creating a short if you want to replace the wiring keep resetting the breaker when it trips and it won't take long before the insulation melts.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your connecting the wires together has caused a short. Why did you connect the two wires together?

Comment: If I don’t connect them there is no power going to the switch.